# Does google analytics work for service on android?

Tags: android, google-analytics

I want to track user's action on service. For example,How often they would have started the service,etc.

Does Google Analytics provide any API for these?

`EasyTracker.getInstance(this).activityStart(this)` is only used for Activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can track this as an event.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/events

```
EasyTracker easyTracker = EasyTracker.getInstance(this);

  // MapBuilder.createEvent().build() returns a Map of event fields and values
  // that are set and sent with the hit.
  easyTracker.send(MapBuilder
      .createEvent("ui_action",     // Event category (required)
                   "button_press",  // Event action (required)
                   "play_button",   // Event label
                   null)            // Event value
      .build()
  );
```

Although, you could send an event when the user performs an action instead, to start the service. That would be more convenient.